# Glue Job failing due to inability to download script from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I am working on creating an AWS Glue ETL process to pull CSV data from S3 into an AWS Aurora DB.

I have successfully created and run the crawlers for both the source file and the destination DB table.  I have also created the ETL Job, performed the mappings and saved the auto-generated script.  All (S3, DB, Glue) are located in the same region.

When running the ETL job, it errors out with the following messages

```
fatal error: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: <REDACTED>
Error downloading script: fatal error: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: <REDACTED>
```

In the Cloudwatch Log, I have 2 relevant messages:

```
Specifying us-west-2 while copying script. 
S3 copy with region specified failed. Falling back to not specifying region.
```

I have tried the following:

- Verified IAM role has access to S3
- Granted full access (public, read & write) to the script file as well as the .temp file; I don't think this is necessary but in the spirit of ruling out things ...
- Verified SSL (Port 443) on EC2 for both inbound and outbound.

Any other thoughts or solutions are appreciated!

Comment: Prabhakar Reddy's answer was correct; needed to add HTTPS (port 443) outbound rules on the ACL and the VPC.

Comment: could you please mark it as answered if it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the VPC which you have used to launch Glue job is missing S3 endpoint. As the traffic will not leave [AWS network](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/vpc-endpoint.html) there will not be internet access inside your Glue job's VPC. So if you want to connect to S3 then you need to add it to your VPC.

Refer to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/glue-troubleshooting-errors.html#error-s3-timeout) to know more and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/setup-vpc-for-glue-access.html) to make sure that you properly configured security groups